# Match lookup value order wise

Tags: excel, match

I trying to achieve the return lookup value the following orders wise {"TYPE 3","TYPE 4","TYPE 1","TYPE 6","TYPE 2","TYPE 5","OK"}

I am apply the following formula in H3=IF(MATCH(F$2,$A$2,0),VLOOKUP($F3,$A$4:$C$58,MATCH(F$1,$B$2,0)+2,FALSE)) but lookup return first value only.

Please assist me.

***Screenshot***
[image]

```
DATA                    ELECTRICAL      
VT245   ELECTRICAL              VT245   DESIRED RESULT  FORMULA RETURN
SIZE    ITEM    TEXT            3936    TYPE 3  TYPE 1
3936    2856    TYPE 1          4016    TYPE 4  TYPE 1
3936    2857    TYPE 2          4011    TYPE 1  TYPE 1
3936    2858    TYPE 3          2311    TYPE 6  TYPE 1
3936    2859    TYPE 4          4000    TYPE 2  TYPE 1
3936    2860    TYPE 5          4028    TYPE 5  TYPE 1
3936    2861    TYPE 6          4031    OK  OK
3936    2862    OK                  

4016    2856    TYPE 1                  
4016    2857    TYPE 2                  
4016    2858    TYPE 3                  
4016    2859    TYPE 4                  
4016    2860    TYPE 5                  
4016    2861    TYPE 6                  
4016    2862    OK                  

4011    2856    TYPE 1                  
4011    2857    TYPE 2                  
4011    2858    TYPE 3                  
4011    2859    TYPE 4                  
4011    2860    TYPE 5                  
4011    2861    TYPE 6                  
4011    2862    OK                  

2311    2856    TYPE 1                  
2311    2857    TYPE 2                  
2311    2858    TYPE 3                  
2311    2859    TYPE 4                  
2311    2860    TYPE 5                  
2311    2861    TYPE 6                  
2311    2862    OK                  

4000    2856    TYPE 1                  
4000    2857    TYPE 2                  
4000    2858    TYPE 3                  
4000    2859    TYPE 4                  
4000    2860    TYPE 5                  
4000    2861    TYPE 6                  
4000    2862    OK                  

4028    2856    TYPE 1                  
4028    2857    TYPE 2                  
4028    2858    TYPE 3                  
4028    2859    TYPE 4                  
4028    2860    TYPE 5                  
4028    2861    TYPE 6                  
4028    2862    OK                  

4031    2856    OK                  
4031    2857    OK                  
4031    2858    OK                  
4031    2859    OK                  
4031    2860    OK                  
4031    2861    OK                  
4031    2862    OK
```

Comment: I am confused, how do you know which TYPE is for SIZE? Because the VLOOKUP will show you only the first value found.

Comment: Its general text it's not belongs to any size or item. For example: 4031 all the row's"ok" then formula return as ok if return any other  text against the size then formula return   above mentioned order wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In G2 and copied down to suit:

```
="TYPE "&IF(F3=4031,"OK",MATCH(F3,{4011,4000,3936,4016,4028,2311},0))
```

Comment: Thank for your help. Formula work fine. The text uncommonly like PA, QA, PJ,PR the formula not working. How to resolve the issue